# How to configure an echo pod on different port instead of port 80 in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
       name: echo-pod
       namespace: echo
    spec:
       containers:
       - name: nginx
         image: nginx
         ports:
            -  containerPort: 81
```

Tried to connect on port 81, by running above yaml file, but it is still connecting on port 80.
Checked connection using telnet

The ip of echo -pod is 192.168.211.1

## Able to connect echo pod  from busybox pod(which is already exists) on port 80 but not on port 81. you can observe following

```
root@ip-172-31-16-143:~# kubectl exec busybox -- telnet 192.168.211.1 80
Connected to 192.168.211.1

root@ip-172-31-16-143:~# kubectl exec busybox -- telnet 192.168.211.1 81
telnet: can't connect to remote host (192.168.211.1): Connection refused
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: You should change the nginx config to listen on port 81 instead. `containerPort` is for documentation only, it really changes nothing. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/ ctrl+f for `containerPort` here

Comment: can we make a connection on multiple ports on both  80 and 81

Comment: no you can not make a connection on multiple port...what are you exactly trying to do ? Can you use  a kubernetes service with a different port pointing to 80?

Comment: i'm trying to connect one pod to another pod (which is listening on different port  other than 80).                                                                                                          
can you help me how to do, kuberentes service with a different port pointing to 80

Answer (score 7):

By defining `containerPort: 81` on your pod template, you are only changing the [exposed container port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose), but your Nginx server will still listen on port 80 (as it is configured by default).

**You need to change the Nginx [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) configuration to match your new exposed port**.

*Different from mostly docker implementations, Nginx doesn't support such configs by using environment variables (see [Using environment variables in Nginx configuration](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) on their Docker Hub page).*

If you wish to adapt the Nginx default configuration, you need to create a new `nginx.conf` with the `listen 81;` config, then replace the original using `COPY` in your Dockerfile to create a custom image `FROM` nginx.

If your prefer an "one-line workaround" still using the original Nginx image, you can change the command/args to replace the listen config on every start:

```
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ["sed -i 's/listen  .*/listen 81;/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
    ports:
    - containerPort: 81
```

Comment: Instead of changing the nginx config file, can we make a kuberentes service with a different port pointing to 80

Answer (score -1):

Use Kubernetes service(cluster IP type) for connecting from one pod to another pod.

Create a service as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: echo
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 81
      targetPort: 80
```

Add a label `app: nginx` to the nginx pod so that the service selects the pod as backend.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: echo-pod
  namespace: echo
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

Then you can use the cluster IP of the service or better yet DNS of the service and port `81` to connect to the nginx pod from another pod.

To check the cluster IP run `kubectl get svc my-service -n echo`

The DNS will be `my-service.echo.svc.cluster.local`

Then you can use `clusterip:81` or `my-service.echo.svc.cluster.local:81` to connect to nginx pod from another pod.

Comment: In this case, how should i check the connection between two pods

Comment: You don't generally connect directly from one pod to another; you almost always go via a Service as shown here.

Comment: No, i'm able to connect without a service also but it is only on port 80, i mentioned commands above in the question, you can observe

Comment: Thank you Arghya Sadhu, what you mensioned also working